# How to get Fama-French Factors for current month

Tags: factor-models, fama-french

I have developed a strategy based, among other things, on the Fama-French model. For the backtest I used the factors from Ken French web side. But there are only historical factors calculated until the end of June 23. In order to implement strategies based on this model in practice, one would of course need the data up to the current trading day. Is there any side that provides this data up to the present or are there templates (preferably in Python) that calculate these factors exactly as on the Ken French web side, so that one could calculate the factors for the last month oneself?
I have already tried it myself, but this is extremely time-consuming and also practically impossible because on the web side, for example, the exact universe of shares used is not specified anywhere and you would have to work through a lot of papers to find the exact definitions

Comment: The only way you can do it without an impossible amount of work is to have access to CRSP monthly update. If you have access to that date there's plenty of codes out there that would replicate the factors.